# setTimeout doesn't work when trying to fade element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a `tooltip` and trying to hide it **after 9 seconds**, but it does not work for me.

What is happening here that the "tooltip" **is only hidden after loading**, but it does not respond the second time I click on "Touch Me" button.
The "Touch Me" button is `#pop-regalo`

What am I doing wrong in my script?
You can find a demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pop-regalo').hide();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#pop-regalo').fadeIn('slow');
  }, 1000);
});

//--------------------

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pop-regalo").click(function() {
    $("#hola,.layer-2,.tooltip").show();
  });
  $("#hola").click(function() {
    $("#hola,.layer-2").hide();
  });
});

// --------------------

$(function() {
  $('.tooltip');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 9000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif
}

.note {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 70px auto 0
}

#pop-regalo {
  position: fixed;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer
}

#hola {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px 15px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 200px;
  background: #999;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  animation: fadein .75s;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.layer-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: fadein .2s;
  animation: fadein .2s;
  z-index: 999
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -80px
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  right: 110%;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pop-regalo">Touch Me
  <!--<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/4f/ff/3b4fff9dfb958a180863c56d7fcf6326.jpg">-->
</div>

<div class="note">What is happening here that the "tooltip" is only hidden after loading, but it does not respond the second time we click on the red button named Touch Me...?</div>

<div id="hola">Close</div>

<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">A gift for you</span>
</div>

<div class="layer-2"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you have three document readies?

Comment: Also `setTimeout()` does not repeat.  It runs once and is done.  So if you are expecting the logic to repeat after you do the `show()` in your click handler, it's not going to.  You have to put another setTimeout in that handler so it knows it needs to do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger the timeout at the moment you show the tooltip. In your original code, you're only triggering the timeout upon page load, so when if you click the red button for the first time after 9 seconds have already passed, the tooltip would not hide even on the first iteration.

You might also want to save a reference to the timeout instance to a variable and cancel this instance before triggering a new one, so that the tooltip will not be hidden too early when you close the overlay and click the button again while the tooltip is still showing.

```js
var tooltipTimeout;

$(function(){
    $('#pop-regalo').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#pop-regalo').fadeIn('slow');
    },1000);
});

//--------------------

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pop-regalo").click(function(){
    $("#hola,.layer-2,.tooltip").show();
    // clear any old timeout
    window.clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
    // you have to start the timeout after showing the tooltip
    tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
    },9000);
  });
    $("#hola").click(function(){
      $("#hola,.layer-2").hide();
  });
});

// --------------------

$(function(){
    // the code in here is only called once at page load
    // $('.tooltip'); // <= this doesn't do anything
    // setTimeout(function(){
    //     $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
    // },9000);
});
```

```css
html,body {left:0;top:0;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif}

.note {width:50%;margin:70px auto 0}

#pop-regalo {
  position:fixed;
  left:15px;
  top:15px;
  padding:10px 15px;
  color:white;
  background:red;
  cursor:pointer
}

#hola {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    padding:15px 15px 8px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    line-height:200px;
    background:#999;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 1s;
    animation:fadein .75s;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:9999
}

@keyframes fadein{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:0}75%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:0}75%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

.layer-2 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-animation:fadein .2s;
    animation:fadein .2s;
    z-index:999
}

.tooltip {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  top:140px;
  left:100%;
  margin-left:-80px
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  background:#000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  right: 110%;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pop-regalo">Touch Me
<!--<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/4f/ff/3b4fff9dfb958a180863c56d7fcf6326.jpg">-->
</div>

<div class="note">The tooltip will show upon button click and then hide after 9 seconds.</div>

<div id="hola">Close</div>

<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">A gift for you</span>
</div>

<div class="layer-2"></div>
```

Comment: Given that it's a class selector on the click handler, the inner lookup of the class has a chance of being too broad.  It would be safer to apply the fade out to `this` instead.  Or in the least, to the same elements that `show()` was executed on.

Comment: You're referring to the selectors for the show/hide/fadeOut calls? Good catch, but I'd say this goes beyond the scope of the question. But OP will probably want to address that in his real-life scenario.

Comment: We're here to help people learn.  That isn't limited to the scope of the question presented.  If there are other issues we see in a question that are not asked about, it's still within our goal of teaching people to point them out.

Comment: Agreed, but we don't know whether it's the OPs intention to show/hide multiple tooltips on the page at once. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: My second comment was simply a counter point to your statement that "this goes beyond the scope of the question" as a potential argument to not bring up the potential issue.

Comment: Wasn't intended as such, your comment is perfectly valid and sensible! :)

Comment: Thanks!, **Connun**. Very clean and tidy. Cheers!